# How to compute sum of all combinations

Tags: combinations

I remember some things from college about computing permutations and combinations, but I don't really recall if we ever learned any alternative to the formula I'm about to describe. In this case, I want to know how many full combinations (the nomenclature is probably not correct) you can generate from a set of `n` elements. That is, from `n` elements, you may choose 1, 2, 3, ... all the way up to choosing all `n`.

I think that [this](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B%7Bn%7D%5Cchoose%7Bk%7D%7D%7D) formula does the trick, but is there any simpler alternative? Specifically, I'd rather have a non-iterative one (without the sum loop). Ideas?

Comment: If "combinations" means "subsets", then, as Marcus Stuhr answered, it's $2^n$.

Page 30 here: [https://books.google.com/books?id=PS8lQQ8AOHYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=sadovsky+discrete+mathematics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8z-_Vv9TTAhUKSiYKHSjgB5UQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=subsets&f=false]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via binomial theorem:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (1)^{n-k}(1)^k = (1+1)^n = 2^n$$

If you aren't counting the $k=0$ case then you subtract $1$ from this.

Comment: Ah, it does ring a bell :) thank you!

Comment: why do you put one and one then factor it?